# mod_wsgi-express in Docker : SSLCipherSuite and SSLProtocol

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-wsgi

I'm running mod_wsgi-express in Docker using [Graham's image](https://hub.docker.com/r/grahamdumpleton/mod-wsgi-docker/).  I want users to access my site over HTTPS.

When I run the site through SSL Labs, I can see that SSLv3 and TLS1.0 are on, as are the RC4 ciphers.  I don't want any of that, so I need access to the `SSLCipherSuite` and `SSLProtocol` directives in the `httpd.conf` file.

But, looking at the options from `mod_wsgi-express start-server --help` and the HTTPS stanzas in the generated file, I don't see any way to access these variables.

```
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_HTTPS>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen localhost:443
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen 443
</IfDefine>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
<Location />
<IfVersion < 2.4>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
Require all denied
</IfVersion>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ALLOW_LOCALHOST>
Allow from localhost
</IfDefine>
</Location>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile cert-file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile key-file.key
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName my-server.me
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_ALIAS>
ServerAlias None
</IfDefine>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile cert-file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile key-file.ky
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HTTPS_ONLY>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HSTS_POLICY>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security None
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SSL_ENVIRONMENT>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_REDIRECT_WWW>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName unspecified
Redirect permanent / https://my-server.me:443/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile cert-file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile key-file.key
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

</IfDefine>
```

Is there a way to access `SSLCipherSuite` and `SSLProtocol` that I am missing, or am I stuck building my own `httpd.conf` and injecting it into the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `ssl.conf` file and add your directives in it. Then add the option:

```
--include-file ssl.conf
```

to `mod_wsgi-express` when run.

These will be included at the end of the generated `httpd.conf` file which I think for these options is okay.

If doesn't help, then jump on to the mod_wsgi mailing list and we can discuss further there. I may have to add a `--ssl-options` option for including a snippet file with SSL stuff in it, so is included at the correct place in the generated file.

Comment: This worked like a champ.  My ssl.conf file is off of https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ and I inject it into the image with COPY.